# Android NDK: Missing LOCAL_MODULE before including BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

I'm trying to setup a test NDK project in Eclipse/ADT following [this tutorial](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/).

I've created a fresh new Android project "Test1", in which I've added these 2 files:

```
c:\Workspace\Test1\jni\Android.mk
c:\Workspace\Test1\jni\ndkfoo.c
```

This is in `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ndkfoo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ndkfoo.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But when I try to compile it, I get this error:

```
c:\Workspace\Test1\jni>ndk-build
c:/android-ndk-r10d/build/core/build-shared-library.mk:23: *** Android NDK: Missing LOCAL_MODULE before including BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY in c:/Workspace/Test1//jni/Android.mk    .  Stop.
```

But I do have a `LOCAL_MODULE    := ndkfoo` clause in `Android.mk`, so I don't understand why I am getting this error!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting this in case some other poor soul tries to copy/paste directly from that tutorial - there is something wrong with the spaces on the line `LOCAL_MODULE    := ndkfoo`.

I think they are not proper spaces but some weird Unicode character which was messing with ndk-build, because I looked at them with a hex editor and they were `0xC2 0xA0 0xC2 0xA0 0xC2 0xA0` instead of `0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20` (which is normal spaces).

Anyone copying from their tutorial will have this error, unfortunately.

If you try to copy from the question here it should be OK, I think SO has somehow fixed them to normal spaces, but on the original site they are weird Unicode spaces that will cause `ndk-build` to fail.

**Edit:** Apparently those are [non-breaking spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). I have no idea if it's true, but I think that ndk-build didn't recognize them as whitespace, so they became part of the variable name, so I was defining a variable called `"LOCAL_MODULE   "`, instead of `"LOCAL_MODULE"`, which is why it was complaining about the variable being undefined.

Comment: Yep, similar problem, but for me it was the line endings. Suggest either getting hold of a text editor that will convert these for you (Notepad++ under Windows has an option for this), or be sure to manually delete and replace every space using the spacebar and every line ending using enter.