# Missing LOCAL_MODULE before including BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I am trying to set a NDK project in Eclipse. I have build the NDK as my sample programs are working properly. But, now when I am running my code I am facing this error

> *** Android NDK: Missing LOCAL_MODULE before including BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY in jni/Android.mk    .  Stop.

I have tried solving it through this question
[Android NDK: Missing LOCAL_MODULE before including BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747232/android-ndk-missing-local-module-before-including-build-shared-library)

But, Its not working. Please help me. 
Following is my **Android.mk** file

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:= off
OPENCV_MK_PATH:D:\FYP\darwinwallet-master\OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\OpenCV.mk
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
include $(OPENCV_MK_PATH)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:=D:\FYP\darwinwallet-master\OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\include\
LOCAL_MODULE:=native_wallet
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=jni_recognizer.cpp NativeVision/vision.cpp
LOCAL_CFLAGS=-ffast-math -O3 -funroll-loopsLOCAL_LDLIBS+=-llog -ldl
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And following is my **build-shared-library.mk**

```
LOCAL_BUILD_SCRIPT := BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY
LOCAL_MAKEFILE     := $(local-makefile)
$(call check-defined-LOCAL_MODULE,$(LOCAL_BUILD_SCRIPT))
$(call check-LOCAL_MODULE,$(LOCAL_MAKEFILE))
$(call check-LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME)
my := TARGET_
$(call handle-module-filename,lib,$(TARGET_SONAME_EXTENSION))
$(call handle-module-built)
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARY
include $(BUILD_SYSTEM)/build-module.mk
```

Comment: **build-shared-library.mk** is not yours; it is part of the NDK, and you are expected not to fiddle with it too much. You can remove it from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use backslash in your make files, it's too dangerous. Even on Windows, you can use forward slashes, i.e. change all **`\`** to **`/`**. This will resolve your problem immediately.

Specifically, the line where you define `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` ends with **`\`** which means for **make** that it does not end. **make** dutifully joins the next line, so what it actually sees is something like

```
…
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:=D:\…\include\LOCAL_MODULE:=native_wallet
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=jni_recognizer.cpp NativeVision/vision.cpp
…
```

But actually, there is no need to re-define `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` after you **`include OpenCV.mk`**. This script takes care of setting the include paths, flags, and library dependencies for you.